# Destroying one of the Great Pyramids without killing the protagonist

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology

A woman finds herself inside the Great Pyramid of Kheops when a bunch of terrorists starts blowing it down from outside.

The woman manages to find a way out but before being able to leave the Pyramid, a new explosion ejects her out and she crashes into the ground.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_injury), the main damages caused by a blast are the following ones:

- Primary injuries (intern ones): damage is inflicted upon her auditory system. (Her tympanic membrane may be perforated by the intensity of the pressure waves.) The overpressure also affects her lungs and the hollow organs of the gastrointestinal tract.
- Secondary injuries caused by other objects (here rocks) propelled during the explosion.
- Tertiary blast injuries: bone fractures because of the blast wind that throws her against the ground.

=> As the explosion occurs in a confined space, causing structural collapse of the Pyramid, the damages should be even more important.

Considering that I'd like her to survive, is it realistic to say that when the last explosion occurs, she is close enough to one extremity of the Pyramid to avoid being hit by rocks while being ejected and close enough to the base to survive the crash against the ground?

Comment: *"I'd like her to survive. How is that possible?"* She has to be wearing an armor made of the strongest material ever: a plot armor.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to make yourself familiar with our standards. You are basically giving us the seed of a concept and are asking us to develop it for you, defining how the bad guys destroy the pyramid and how the heroine makes out of it alive. Please narrow down your question to a single, answerable problem.

Comment: This looks like a story set in a world, and not building a world itself. This is one of the specific close reasons on this site, and it'll stay valid even if you will fix "too broad" issue.

Comment: Can you insert the link to the wikipedia page? It's good that you summarized the content.

Comment: To blow a Great Pyramid from _outside_, a nuclear device would be needed.

Comment: an explosion big enough to destroy the great pyramid will turn her into hamburger, the great pyramid is basically just a pile of stone blocks, the only way to destroy it is to move most of the stone blocks, which is a massive explosion, the shock wave alone will kill her even hundreds of meters away.

Comment: Two issues - one, the Great Pyramid is basically a mountain.  There are no substantial empty spaces in it; the individual chambers are tiny components of its overall volume.  So "structural collapse" is not a thing that can happen to it.  Two - "reality-check".  Everyone's suggesting plot armour, so you may have mistagged.

Comment: Hi S.Fox, welcome to Worldbuilding! Looks like you've gotten a lot of good feedback already that I agree with. I'd like to recommend our Sandbox to you, a perfect place for questions that need a little polishing up before they're ready for main. Until then, I've voted to place your question on hold so you don't get swamped with unhelpful answers.

Comment: The question of "How can you collapse the Great Pyramid of Kheops (Cheops)?" is where I would start.  Forget someone being there trying to survive for now.  Figure out *how* and *if* what you want to do is even possible.  Once you know how to do it, or decide on a less action that is actually possible, you can move on to the next question.

Comment: Suggestion: "Terrorists are trying to destroy the Great Pyramid of Kheops (Cheops). [Link to info, summarize important things like size, materials, etc.] [Add your definition of "destroy" and the minimum/maximum damage you consider acceptable.] How would it be possible to do this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gust of wind.**

In this scenario the second explosion is not right next to her or on top of her.  It is on the far side of the pyramid and the interior spaces channel and also blunt the expanding front of gases.  A gust of wind blasts out the exit where she is and throws her through the air.

---

**Protected by a block**

In this scenario, she has her back to a block of stone and this is thrown as a piece by the explosion with her in front of it.  She is badly bruised but the bulk of the block protects her from the shock wave - persons and things on either side of her are not so lucky.  The block lands on top of her.  It is big enough that it does not crush her; she is in a sandy depression underneath the block and that is where she regains consciousness later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing.  Any explosion big enough to pick you up and toss you, is big enough to kill you instantly.

Forget Hollywood, forget Michael Bay.  Your protagonist is dead.

To make things worse, you want to destroy the whole pyramid.  That would take a nuclear explosion as large as the biggest humanity has ever created.  Not only is your protagonist dead, most of country is too.

If you want the protagonist to survive, you need plot armor.

You could try an excuse like the ground opens up in the pyramid, and they fall through and down into the suspected water ways below, where the protagonist emerges safely near the river.  These water ways occasionally crop up as scientifically proven so you might be able to use them.

Comment: This is not strictly true; explosions are weird things.  Edith O'Connell was a child during the Halifax explosion who was tossed into the air by the explosion and landed injured but alive.  She was lucky, of course, but it's not impossible.